# What translation process do you use for your web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, translation

We're working on some Ruby on Rails web application which is currently in English but should be translated to more languages. We deploy new version of application to production every 2 weeks. Translators are a separate team.

We have a special page in admin area for making translations. Dictionaries are stored as YAML-files. We can let translator edit dictionaries in production and open language for visitors then it will be ready. Another way is to let translators to work on staging server and merge translations before deployment to productions.

Do somebody know a good process to synchronize work of developers and translators?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add ruby in the title, please

Comment: I'm working on RoR application but the question was not about something RoR specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

37signals launched [Tolk](http://github.com/dhh/tolk), a tool they used to translate Basecamp into several languages. I've not used it myself, but seems a handy tool to automate some parts of the process. It may be worth giving it a look.

Comment: Just for sake of completeness of my answer, their article about it is here http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2315-parlez-vous-franais-basecamp-goes-international

Answer (score 0):

Did not you try http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/ ?
If you go with that, translators and developers can work parallel. Translators can use POEDIT to find the text in application and make the translation.

Comment: Rail's provided i18n support is imho much kinder to use than gettext. (Not to mention, I didn't see any built-in Ruby knowledge in gettext's manual.)

When a Rails developer puts a new string into the view, it is simply a message identifier for the message catalog; then the "native language" is written in the native language YAML. The translators just need the YAML files. No need to bother them with the rest of the source.